# Can you zip or use a custom join operator in non-expression linq?

Tags: linq, join

I have multiple sequences I want to zip in a more readable way such that I could write

```
a.Zip(b)
```

in query syntax as

```
From a in Foo1
Join b in Foo2
```

without the result being a cross join

or

```
From a in Foo1
Zip b in Foo2
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I really can't follow what you're trying to do or how you want to do it. Are you just asking whether there's query expression support for Zip? You should specify language, too...

Comment: @jon - well, I am currently working in Vb, but I primarily do C#. I was hoping to use extension methods to do what Tomas is suggesting below in his from f in first.Zip() example, via a custom join operator or other that I don't have to write in expression literals. I can't find what the other way of writing linq is called, but it's what you have before the compiler translates it into an expression or expression tree.

Comment: I think I know what Maslow wants because I want the same thing. Zip is fine for two IEnums, but what about 3 or 4 or more? Then it's long and complicated. But query syntax, e.g. `from a in Foo1 from b in Foo2` creates a cartesian product rather than a zipping, so that's undesirable. A typical use-case for what I/we want is when you have parallel arrays and then want to put them into a collection of Tuples or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard `Zip` method allows you to write something like (using C#):

```
from t in first.Zip(second, (f, s) => new { First = f, Second = s }
select ... t.First ... t.Second;
```

I think this should be readable enough. Your question seems to suggest that you'd like to be able to create your own keyword e.g. `zip` and extend the C# query expressions using it. This is not possible in C# or Visual Basic (but I agree it would be nice in a way).

With some effort, you can *redefine* what standard C# query construct does, so that `join` would behave like `zip` (In that case, the `equals` part of the query would not be needed, so you'd have a lot of syntactic noise). Possibly, you could also redefine what `from` clause. I didn't try it, but I believe you could get something like:

```
from f in first.Zip()
from s in second.AddToZip()
from t in second.AddToZip()
select ... f ... s ... t ...;
```

I wrote an article that describes how to do this *redefining* for the `group by` clause ([Using custom grouping operator in LINQ](http://tomasp.net/blog/custom-linq-grouping.aspx)), so this can give you an idea how this can be done.

(But honestly, I think that the standard `Zip` method should be fine. The redefinition of operators is quite subtle. The `group by` example may be more appealing because grouping using method is uglier, but even that is on the edge...)

Comment: +1 - thanks this is a jumping off point, if I can follow it and apply it my context it looks pretty good. Then again the whole drive here may be the result of insufficient Separation of Concerns or refactoring.